# Multiple Distributed Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, distributed-availability-groups

Say we have 3 availability groups DB1-AG, DB2-AG, DB3-AG.

According to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16), we can create distributed availability groups [DB1-AG, DB2-AG] and [DB2-AG, DB3-AG].
Where DB1-AG is a primary replicating to DB2-AG, and DB2-AG is then replicating to DB3-AG.

Is a configuration like this possible:
[DB1-AG, DB3-AG] and [DB2-AG, DB3-AG]
Where both DB1-AG and DB2-AG are primaries, replicating into DB3-AG?

I have a feeling it isn't due to the potential for conflicts between 2 DBs, of the same name, existing in both DB1-AG and DB2-AG.
Assuming this is the case, is there a way to get DB1-AG and DB2-AG to replicate into the same availability group?
Or would I need a 4th availability group and configure things as [DB1-AG, DB3-AG] and [DB2-AG, DB4-AG]?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where both DB1-AG and DB2-AG are primaries, replicating into DB3-AG?

Maybe it's the way you're naming things, this would not be possible as the distributed AG is a copy of the AG, thus you cannot combine availability groups through a distributed availability group.

> I have a feeling it isn't due to the potential for conflicts between 2 DBs, of the same name, existing in both DB1-AG and DB2-AG.

This is also correct, can't use the same database or database name.

> Assuming this is the case, is there a way to get DB1-AG and DB2-AG to replicate into the same availability group?

No, these are individual AGs and making them distributed doesn't change that, they still have to stay individual AGs. If you want them combined, make them one AG, then you can create a distributed AG off of that. Otherwise, you'll need another instance as you've already stated in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)